# JS promise not resolving as expected

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

The following two functions exchange promise-resolution data. The second function is supposed to return the object to the first function's internal promise's then, but it doesn't.

```
let functionA = function (stuff) {
var responseToGet;
return fetch(someURL
{
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {headers},
})
.then((resp) => {
    responseToGet = resp;
    return functionB(responseToGet)
})
.then((respFromB) => {
    console.log('respFromB', respFromB); // WHY IS THIS UNDEFINED INSTEAD OF TRUE/FALSE ?
    if (respFromB.status)
        return null;
    else
        return respFromB.jsonObj;
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});}



let functionB = function(response)
{
response.json().then((r2) => {
    if (something)
        return Promise.resolve({status: true, jsonObj: null});
    else
        return Promise.resolve({status: false, jsonObj: r2});
})
.done();}
```

Comment: Your `functionB` doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: What is that `.done()` call?

Comment: @Bergi
.done is like .then and .catch but it for a successful resolution without any exception throw.

Can you please modify it to get the result i'm expecting?

Comment: `return Promise.resolve({status: true, jsonObj: null});` is superfluous. You just want `return {status: true, jsonObj: null};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to call 'done' function.
Just return a promise from functionB

Example:

```
var functionA = function (stuff) {
    var responseToGet;
    return fetch("http://httpbin.org/gzip",
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {}
        })
        .then(function (resp) {
            responseToGet = resp;
            return functionB(responseToGet)
        }).then(function (respFromB) {
            console.log('respFromB', respFromB); // WHY IS THIS UNDEFINED INSTEAD OF TRUE/FALSE ?
            if (respFromB.status)
                return null;
            else
                return respFromB.jsonObj;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

var functionB = function (response) {
    var promise = response.json().then(function (r2) {
        if (r2)
            return Promise.resolve({status: true, jsonObj: null});
        else
            return Promise.resolve({status: false, jsonObj: r2});
    });

    return promise;
}
```